# Passing parameters with initWithParent methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c

method

```
-(id) initWithParent:(id)parent
{
 // do something
}
```

calling of the above method

```
theM3u8Parser = [[M3u8Parser alloc] initWithParent:self];
```

That method works perfect. But now I also need to pass a NSString into the method.

So i changed it to

```
-(id) initWithParent:(id)parent:(NSString*)str
{
//do something
}
```

Then i call it like so

```
theM3u8Parser = [[M3u8Parser alloc] initWithParent:self:aStr];
```

But now the app crashes with a 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[M3u8Parser initWithParent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a10a50'

Is it not possible to modify this method? If so is there a way of accessing the string which is a member variable of the parent class?

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible to modify the method. Try it like this:

```
- (id)initWithParent:(id)parent andWithString:(NSString *)str;
```

Then call it like this:

```
theM3u8Parser = [[M3u8Parser alloc] initWithParent:self andWithString:aStr];
```